# BI Publisher conditional field hiding based on length of text in RTF

Tags: rtf, obiee, bi-publisher

I am using BI publisher and trying to show/hide fields based on if the field is null or not. in RTF I have tried using If statement like below but it is not working

```
<?if@inlines:string-length(ABC)!=''?>
<?end if?>
```

any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test if an element is not null, use this rather than checking it's length:

```
<?if:ELEMENT!=''?>
Content that will show if data is present in element.
<?end if?>
```

Comment: Thank you, can I apply the condition based on another element ? since I am having a question and answer type of data ?
for example, if there is no answer, dont display the question ?
Thanks

Comment: Also, I have noticed that in the xml, there is a self closing tag if the filed is empty. can we use that ?
<ANS_TEXT/>

Comment: Yes, you can do that. If it's in a table, you can even encapsulate the whole row so it doesn't display any of it. And yes, the self closed tag is treated as Null. You can download the BI Publisher Desktop/Word add-in and test things out on your local machine easily rather than uploading every time, not sure if you've tried that. Find the tool that's installed called "template viewer."

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<?xdofx:length(char)?>`

Comment: can I change it to <?xdofx:length(char) != 0?>